# How to Select rows based on two columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to select rows based on values of two column,

Here is the structure of Table,

```
ID | Weight | Page
------------------
 1 |  1     | 1
 2 |  2     | 1
 3 |  1     | 2
 4 |  2     | 2
```

Now I want to select all IDs from page1 and all ids from page2 but for page2 weight should be <=1

How can I select those IDs?

Thanx

Comment: As a side note, `weight` actually represents a positive contiguous-range type.  That is, there's no such thing as "exactly a pound", it's really "the closest we can get is one pound".  In light of this (and how representation add **zeroes** when more precision is added), you shouldn't be using an inclusive upper-bound, you should be using an [exclusive upper-bound](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  It makes dealing with ranges way easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE Page = 1 OR (Page = 2 AND Weight <= 1)
```

This way, you get both IDs from page 1 and IDs from page 2 with weight <= 1, thanks to boolean logic group in this query

Comment: +1 For not having pre-coffee typos, like myself, in original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of parens in SQL queries to form logical conditions.  Condition 1 OR (Condition 2) - where condition 2 would have multiple parts.

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table
WHERE Page = 1 OR (Page = 2 AND Weight <= 1)
```

This is saying if it's page 1 then grab it.  If it's not page 1 then if it's page 2 and also has weight <= 1 then grab it.